# How to host or run a legacy ASP.NET app on a Windows 2019 Server?

Tags: asp.net, legacy

I've been tasked with getting a 10 year old ASP.NET app running after the server it was running on failed. I'm unsure of the original environment it was on other than that is was an older version of windows server, and I would prefer to use the latest.

So far, I'm able to build the solution file from source using MsBuild.exe (output included), which creates a directory, PrecompiledWeb, which is similar to the main project directory, but with different files in bin directory.

However I'm not sure how to get a webserver to serve this. I'm familiar with modern dotnet-core apps that can be run using "dotnet run" or by publishing the app and running "dotnet Project.dll", but neither of these methods work.

If there are multiple ways of hosting this site I'd prefer the most time efficent option, this is a small site running behind a reverse proxy and doesn't need to be very feature rich.

Output of MsBuild.exe:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.8.3761.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 8/24/2020 2:29:07 PM.
Project "C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.sln" (1) is building "C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj : warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or re
target your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be
correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /DarkSkiesMusic -p DarkSkiesMusic\ -u -f -d PrecompiledWeb\DarkSkiesMusic\
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucTrafficReport.ascx.cs(59): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeMeasurementUnit' is obsolete: 'This enum is obsolete now. Use the DateTimeMeasureUnit enum instead.' [C:\U
sers\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucTrafficReport.ascx.cs(59): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeGridAlignment' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use DateTimeScaleOptions.GridAlignmen
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucTrafficReport.ascx.cs(60): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeMeasureUnit' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use DateTimeScaleOptions.MeasureUnit in
stead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucTrafficReport.ascx.cs(63): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeOptions' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use AxisX.Label.DateTimeOptions or AxisY.La
bel.DateTimeOptions instead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucTrafficReport.ascx.cs(64): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeOptions' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use AxisX.Label.DateTimeOptions or AxisY.La
bel.DateTimeOptions instead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucTrafficReport.ascx.cs(66): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisLabel.Antialiasing' is obsolete: 'This property is now obsolete. Use the EnableAntialiasing property instead.'
 [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucLoginTracking.ascx.cs(89): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeMeasurementUnit' is obsolete: 'This enum is obsolete now. Use the DateTimeMeasureUnit enum instead.' [C:\U
sers\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucLoginTracking.ascx.cs(89): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeGridAlignment' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use DateTimeScaleOptions.GridAlignmen
t instead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucLoginTracking.ascx.cs(90): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeMeasureUnit' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use DateTimeScaleOptions.MeasureUnit in
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucLoginTracking.ascx.cs(93): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeOptions' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use AxisX.Label.DateTimeOptions or AxisY.La
bel.DateTimeOptions instead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucLoginTracking.ascx.cs(94): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeOptions' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use AxisX.Label.DateTimeOptions or AxisY.La
bel.DateTimeOptions instead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucLoginTracking.ascx.cs(96): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisLabel.Antialiasing' is obsolete: 'This property is now obsolete. Use the EnableAntialiasing property instead.'
 [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\Main.aspx.cs(17): warning CS0219: The variable 'TabX' is assigned but its value is never used [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\Main.aspx.cs(18): warning CS0219: The variable 'ShowTab' is assigned but its value is never used [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj" (default targets).



Build succeeded.

"C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
(Build target) ->
  C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj : warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or
retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not b
e correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucTrafficReport.ascx.cs(59): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeMeasurementUnit' is obsolete: 'This enum is obsolete now. Use the DateTimeMeasureUnit enum instead.' [C:
\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucTrafficReport.ascx.cs(59): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeGridAlignment' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use DateTimeScaleOptions.GridAlignm
ent instead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucTrafficReport.ascx.cs(60): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeMeasureUnit' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use DateTimeScaleOptions.MeasureUnit
instead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucTrafficReport.ascx.cs(63): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeOptions' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use AxisX.Label.DateTimeOptions or AxisY.
Label.DateTimeOptions instead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucTrafficReport.ascx.cs(64): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeOptions' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use AxisX.Label.DateTimeOptions or AxisY.
Label.DateTimeOptions instead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucTrafficReport.ascx.cs(66): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisLabel.Antialiasing' is obsolete: 'This property is now obsolete. Use the EnableAntialiasing property instead
.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucLoginTracking.ascx.cs(89): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeMeasurementUnit' is obsolete: 'This enum is obsolete now. Use the DateTimeMeasureUnit enum instead.' [C:
\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucLoginTracking.ascx.cs(89): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeGridAlignment' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use DateTimeScaleOptions.GridAlignm
ent instead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucLoginTracking.ascx.cs(90): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeMeasureUnit' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use DateTimeScaleOptions.MeasureUnit
instead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucLoginTracking.ascx.cs(93): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeOptions' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use AxisX.Label.DateTimeOptions or AxisY.
Label.DateTimeOptions instead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucLoginTracking.ascx.cs(94): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.DateTimeOptions' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete now. Use AxisX.Label.DateTimeOptions or AxisY.
Label.DateTimeOptions instead.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\UserControls\ucLoginTracking.ascx.cs(96): warning CS0618: 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisLabel.Antialiasing' is obsolete: 'This property is now obsolete. Use the EnableAntialiasing property instead
.' [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\Main.aspx.cs(17): warning CS0219: The variable 'TabX' is assigned but its value is never used [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]
  c:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\darkskiesmusic\Main.aspx.cs(18): warning CS0219: The variable 'ShowTab' is assigned but its value is never used [C:\Users\Administrator\DSSMusicSourceCode\DSSMusicSourceCode\DarkSkiesMusic.metaproj]

    15 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:22.26
```

And here are the files associated with this project:

```
C:.
│   DarkSkiesMusic.sln
│
├───.vs
│   ├───config
│   │       applicationhost.config
│   │
│   └───DarkSkiesMusic
│       └───v15
│           │   .suo
│           │
│           └───Server
│               └───sqlite3
│                       db.lock
│                       storage.ide
│                       storage.ide-shm
│                       storage.ide-wal
│
├───darkskiesmusic
│   │   .DS_Store
│   │   AddToPlaylist.aspx
│   │   AddToPlaylist.aspx.cs
│   │   Captcha.aspx
│   │   Captcha.aspx.cs
│   │   FileParser.aspx
│   │   FileParser.aspx.cs
│   │   licenses.licx
│   │   Main.aspx
│   │   Main.aspx.cs
│   │   Main.htm
│   │   PBrowse.aspx
│   │   PBrowse.aspx.cs
│   │   Player.aspx
│   │   Player.aspx.cs
│   │   PlaylistPage.aspx
│   │   PlaylistPage.aspx.cs
│   │   PMain.aspx
│   │   PMain.aspx.cs
│   │   PressPlay.aspx
│   │   PressPlay.aspx.cs
│   │   web.config
│   │   website.publishproj
│   │
│   ├───App_Code
│   │       DataFacade.cs
│   │       DSSMusicSession.cs
│   │       EncryptionMD5.cs
│   │       Enumerations.cs
│   │       linq.dbml
│   │       linq.dbml.layout
│   │       linq.designer.cs
│   │       PrettyUI.cs
│   │       Utilities.cs
│   │       ViewClasses.cs
│   │
│   ├───Bin
│   │       App_Licenses.dll
│   │       DevExpress.Charts.v13.2.Core.dll
│   │       DevExpress.Data.v13.2.dll
│   │       DevExpress.Printing.v13.2.Core.dll
│   │       DevExpress.RichEdit.v13.2.Core.dll
│   │       DevExpress.Utils.v13.2.dll
│   │       DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v13.2.dll
│   │       DevExpress.Web.v13.2.dll
│   │       DevExpress.XtraCharts.v13.2.dll
│   │       DevExpress.XtraCharts.v13.2.Web.dll
│   │       DevExpress.XtraEditors.v13.2.dll
│   │       taglib-sharp.dll
│   │
│   ├───Images
│   │   │   50transparent.png
│   │   │   Background.png
│   │   │   backgroundImage.jpg
│   │   │   backgroundImage.png
│   │   │   BorderStars.jpg
│   │   │   DarkMoonlessNightCD.jpg
│   │   │   DarkMoonlessNightCD.png
│   │   │   DarkSkiesCD.jpg
│   │   │   DarkSkiesCD.png
│   │   │   dssbluesmall.gif
│   │   │   dssNoColor.png
│   │   │   dssNoColorLarge.gif
│   │   │   edit.png
│   │   │   favicon.png
│   │   │   HeaderStars.png
│   │   │   logo.png
│   │   │   MenuSpace.png
│   │   │   music.png
│   │   │   save.png
│   │   │   SmallTab.png
│   │   │   stars.jpg
│   │   │   Tab.png
│   │   │   TowardTheInfiniteCD.png
│   │   │   uploading.gif
│   │   │   UsernameBackground.png
│   │   │   UsernameBackgroundMobile.png
│   │   │   video.png
│   │   │
│   │   ├───Layout
│   │   │       dss_logo.png
│   │   │       header.png
│   │   │       header1.png
│   │   │       header2.png
│   │   │       header3.png
│   │   │       header3alt.png
│   │   │       header4.png
│   │   │       page.jpeg
│   │   │       page.jpg
│   │   │       visitationcd.png
│   │   │
│   │   └───PrettyUI
│   │           Error.png
│   │           Information.png
│   │           Success.png
│   │           Warning.png
│   │
│   ├───JavaScript
│   │       AC_QuickTime.js
│   │       cycle.js
│   │       responsiveslides.min.js
│   │       swfobject.js
│   │
│   ├───Mediaplayer
│   │       dewplayer.swf
│   │       player.swf
│   │
│   ├───Styles
│   │       Main.css
│   │       Mobile.css
│   │       style.css
│   │
│   ├───Tools
│   │       switch.exe
│   │
│   └───UserControls
│           ucAccount.ascx
│           ucAccount.ascx.cs
│           ucAdmin.ascx
│           ucAdmin.ascx.cs
│           ucAlbums.ascx
│           ucAlbums.ascx.cs
│           ucBrowse.ascx
│           ucBrowse.ascx.cs
│           ucCompletePasswordRecovery.ascx
│           ucCompletePasswordRecovery.ascx.cs
│           ucCompleteRegistration.ascx
│           ucCompleteRegistration.ascx.cs
│           ucContactUs.ascx
│           ucContactUs.ascx.cs
│           ucEditTrack.ascx
│           ucEditTrack.ascx.cs
│           ucEditUser.ascx
│           ucEditUser.ascx.cs
│           ucListUsers.ascx
│           ucListUsers.ascx.cs
│           ucLoadPlaylist.ascx
│           ucLoadPlaylist.ascx.cs
│           ucLogin.ascx
│           ucLogin.ascx.cs
│           ucLoginTracking.ascx
│           ucLoginTracking.ascx.cs
│           ucLogout.ascx
│           ucLogout.ascx.cs
│           ucMailUs.ascx
│           ucMailUs.ascx.cs
│           ucMain.ascx
│           ucMain.ascx.cs
│           ucMyTracks.ascx
│           ucMyTracks.ascx.cs
│           ucOrder.ascx
│           ucOrder.ascx.cs
│           ucPlayer.ascx
│           ucPlayer.ascx.cs
│           ucPlaylistBrowser.ascx
│           ucPlaylistBrowser.ascx.cs
│           ucRecoverPassword.ascx
│           ucRecoverPassword.ascx.cs
│           ucRegister.ascx
│           ucRegister.ascx.cs
│           ucSearch.ascx
│           ucSearch.ascx.cs
│           ucTrafficReport.ascx
│           ucTrafficReport.ascx.cs
│           ucUpload.ascx
│           ucUpload.ascx.cs
│           ucUserRecoveries.ascx
│           ucUserRecoveries.ascx.cs
│
└───PrecompiledWeb
    └───DarkSkiesMusic
        │   .DS_Store
        │   AddToPlaylist.aspx
        │   Captcha.aspx
        │   FileParser.aspx
        │   Main.aspx
        │   Main.htm
        │   PBrowse.aspx
        │   Player.aspx
        │   PlaylistPage.aspx
        │   PMain.aspx
        │   PrecompiledApp.config
        │   PressPlay.aspx
        │   web.config
        │   website.publishproj
        │
        ├───bin
        │       App_Code.compiled
        │       App_Code.dll
        │       App_Code.pdb
        │       App_Licenses.dll
        │       App_Web_14srrqoc.dll
        │       App_Web_14srrqoc.pdb
        │       App_Web_ht5b3zjj.dll
        │       App_Web_ht5b3zjj.pdb
        │       App_Web_kpb545cd.dll
        │       App_Web_kpb545cd.pdb
        │       App_Web_pi5yimsm.dll
        │       App_Web_pi5yimsm.pdb
        │       DevExpress.Charts.v13.2.Core.dll
        │       DevExpress.Data.v13.2.dll
        │       DevExpress.Printing.v13.2.Core.dll
        │       DevExpress.RichEdit.v13.2.Core.dll
        │       DevExpress.Utils.v13.2.dll
        │       DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v13.2.dll
        │       DevExpress.Web.v13.2.dll
        │       DevExpress.XtraCharts.v13.2.dll
        │       DevExpress.XtraCharts.v13.2.Web.dll
        │       DevExpress.XtraEditors.v13.2.dll
        │       taglib-sharp.dll
        │
        ├───Images
        │   │   50transparent.png
        │   │   Background.png
        │   │   backgroundImage.jpg
        │   │   backgroundImage.png
        │   │   BorderStars.jpg
        │   │   DarkMoonlessNightCD.jpg
        │   │   DarkMoonlessNightCD.png
        │   │   DarkSkiesCD.jpg
        │   │   DarkSkiesCD.png
        │   │   dssbluesmall.gif
        │   │   dssNoColor.png
        │   │   dssNoColorLarge.gif
        │   │   edit.png
        │   │   favicon.png
        │   │   HeaderStars.png
        │   │   logo.png
        │   │   MenuSpace.png
        │   │   music.png
        │   │   save.png
        │   │   SmallTab.png
        │   │   stars.jpg
        │   │   Tab.png
        │   │   TowardTheInfiniteCD.png
        │   │   uploading.gif
        │   │   UsernameBackground.png
        │   │   UsernameBackgroundMobile.png
        │   │   video.png
        │   │
        │   ├───Layout
        │   │       dss_logo.png
        │   │       header.png
        │   │       header1.png
        │   │       header2.png
        │   │       header3.png
        │   │       header3alt.png
        │   │       header4.png
        │   │       page.jpeg
        │   │       page.jpg
        │   │       visitationcd.png
        │   │
        │   └───PrettyUI
        │           Error.png
        │           Information.png
        │           Success.png
        │           Warning.png
        │
        ├───JavaScript
        │       AC_QuickTime.js
        │       cycle.js
        │       responsiveslides.min.js
        │       swfobject.js
        │
        ├───Mediaplayer
        │       dewplayer.swf
        │       player.swf
        │
        ├───Styles
        │       Main.css
        │       Mobile.css
        │       style.css
        │
        ├───Tools
        │       switch.exe
        │
        └───UserControls
                ucAccount.ascx
                ucAdmin.ascx
                ucAlbums.ascx
                ucBrowse.ascx
                ucCompletePasswordRecovery.ascx
                ucCompleteRegistration.ascx
                ucContactUs.ascx
                ucEditTrack.ascx
                ucEditUser.ascx
                ucListUsers.ascx
                ucLoadPlaylist.ascx
                ucLogin.ascx
                ucLoginTracking.ascx
                ucLogout.ascx
                ucMailUs.ascx
                ucMain.ascx
                ucMyTracks.ascx
                ucOrder.ascx
                ucPlayer.ascx
                ucPlaylistBrowser.ascx
                ucRecoverPassword.ascx
                ucRegister.ascx
                ucSearch.ascx
                ucTrafficReport.ascx
                ucUpload.ascx
                ucUserRecoveries.ascx
```

Comment: What .Net Framework does the legacy app target?  It probably was hosted in IIS.

Comment: your build shows 0 errors.  What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Make sure the same .NET framework installed on the 2019 server by comparing .NET framework settings within your application web.config. Check IIS setup, web application setup, and app pool setup. While accessing your application through the hosted IIS, HTTP codes will help you with further troubleshooting.

Comment: This should work just fine. Use the VS publish application. Use the  publish to a folder. And just installing IIS should work fine. You can then copy over the local published folder from your machine to over write the default site in wwwroot, or create a new site is IIS, and use that folder.